# Compilation Error in JScript File

Tags: javascript

I have create a JavaScript file named `myscripts.js` and I try to include it in other html files like this:

```
<script src="myscripts.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

but an error occurs:

> Script: [location of file] Line: 1 Char: 1 Error: Syntax error Code: 800A03EA Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error

This is the code in `myscripts.js`

```
<p id="demo" align="right"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
</script>
```

Comment: Is that indeed your js file? Why did you put HTML tag inside your JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your js file should only contain this

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
```

The below should go into your html

```
<p id="demo" align="right"></p>
```

Updated:

my html file in full:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title>My HTML File</title> 
</head>

<body>

<p id="demo" align="right"></p>


<script src="myScript.js"></script>
</body>
```

My entire myScript.js file

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
```

I think maybe you need to call the myScript.js file at the end of the file, just before the end body tag, or else it won't find your #demo element

Comment: no, Microsoft JScript compilation error occur  and Date not display on pages